# The minute hand of a clock overtakes the hour hand at intervals of 65 minutes of correct time. How much a day does the clock gain?

Tags: arithmetic, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

The question in the textbook is:

> The minute hand of a clock overtakes the hour hand at intervals of 65 minutes of correct time. How much a day does the clock gain?

**My method**:

The correct clock's minute hand gains over its hour hand in actual 65 minutes = $\dfrac {55}{60} \times 65$ minutes.

The incorrect clock's minute hand gains over its hour hand in actual 65 minutes = 60 minutes.

So the net gain of the incorrect clock over the correct clock in actual 65 minutes = $60 - \dfrac{55}{60} \times 65 = \dfrac {5}{12}$minutes.

So the net gain in 24 hours is $\dfrac{5}{11} \times \dfrac{60 \times 24}{65} = 10.07 $minutes

But the book says the correct answer is $10.2325$ minutes. Also the book uses a different method which I do not understand.

> **Question :** Why is my method incorrect? In my method the incorrect clock's reading should be 5/12 minutes ahead to that of the correct clock's reading after 65 minutes from when both clocks started. But in book's method it is 5/11.

Comment: You have to consider that also the hour hand is moving.

Comment: @EmilioNovati Yes I guess the hour hand is moving faster than usual because of the faster minute hand. If this is true then `net gain = (M_2-H_2)-(M_1-H_1) != M_2-M_1`, M_2=minute hand's reading of 2nd clock, H_1= Hour hand's reading of 2nd clock and so on.

Comment: In a normal clock, the minute hand overtakes the hour hand $22$ times per day.

Comment: @Arthur You are right in 60*24 actual minutes the minute hand gains 55*24 minutes over the hour hand making (55*24)/60 overtakes. But how is this useful in solving this question? P.S: I guess I now understand the book's method.

Comment: It helps you because then you know that when your clock _thinks_ a day has passed, in reality only $22\cdot 65$ minutes have passed.

Comment: @Arthur But the incorrect clock may not make exactly 22 overtakes in a day. Even if it does then 22*65 is the real time when the incorrect clock shows a day -- we need to find the reading of incorrect clock when the real time is 24*60 minutes.

Comment: Yes, it does, as long as the relationship between minute hand and hour hand is correct. _Very_ few clocks get this wrong. Most clocks, however, have a timing problem related to an imperfectly calibrated pendulum / quartz crystal. I would assume that that's the source of your clock's incorrectness.

Comment: @Arthur How can we prove that every clock, whatever its rate(constant) is, makes 22 overlaps a day?

Comment: Assuming 22 overtakes a day gives slightly wrong answer. CAlculation: In 22*65 minutes the incorrect clock is above 10 minutes; in 24*60 minutes the incorrect clock is above (10/1430)*1440 = 10.07 minutes. The right answer is 10.23 minutes.

Comment: The minute hand moves $24$ rounds in a day, while the hour hand moves $2$. $24-2=22$. It happens $11$ times in the am, and at the exact same times in the pm. Those times are roughly 12:00, 1:05, 2:11, 3:16, 4:22, 5:27, 6:33, 7:38, 8:44, 9:49 and 10:55.

Comment: @Arthur I didn't get this line _while the hour hand moves 2. 24−2=22_. If I get it right then this must not be true for the incorrect clock because it runs faster than usual. The incorrect clock overtakes every 65 minutes, so in 60*24 minutes it overtakes (60*24)/65 times, that is 22.1538 times not 22.

Answer (score 1):

On a normal clock, the hand cross each other 11 times in 12 hours, which means that they cross once every $\dfrac{12}{11} = 1.090909…$ hours or every 1 hour, 5 minutes, and 27.272727… seconds. The incorrect clock gains about 27 seconds at every crossing, so each day it gains $22(27.272727… seconds)= 10 minutes every day.

**Note:** These answers are all similar enough that different methods of calculating the answer could be the reason for the varying results.