# A runs 7/4 times as fast as B. If A gives B a start of 84m, how far must the winning post be...?

Tags: arithmetic, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

The problem statement in the book is:

> $A$ runs $7/4$ times as fast as $B$. If $A$ gives $B$ a start of $84$m, how far must the winning post be so that $A$ and $B$ might reach it at the same time?

The solution given in the book is:

> Ratio of the rates of $A$ and $B = 7/4 : 1 = 7:4$.
>   So, in race of $7$m, A gains $3$m over $B$.
>
> ∴ $3$m are gained by $A$ in a race of $7$m.
>
> ∴ $84$m are gained by $A$ in a race of $\left( \dfrac{7}{3} \times 84 \right) m = 196m$.
>
> ∴ Winning post must be 196m away from the starting point.

**Question:** I don't understand how we can use the unitary method after the second step, with 3m gain and 7m distance. Please explain using correct method why is unitary method applicable here.

**My Understanding:** Let $A$'s speed be $a$ and $B$'s speed be $b$. $a:b=7:4$, so $a=7x$ and $b=4x$. Initially $A$ and $B$ are $84m$ apart such that $B$ is ahead of $A$. Now relative speed of $A$ w.r.t. $B$ is $a-b$ in magnitude or $7x-4x=3x$.

In time $t_0$ the separation between $A$ and $B$ is reduced by $3xt_0$ and $A$ travels a net distance w.r.t ground equal to $7xt_0$. Now in time $t_0= \frac 1x$ $A$ moves $7m$ w.r.t. ground and the separation reduced is $3m$. In time $t_0=\frac {1}{3x}$, $A$ travels $\dfrac 73$m and the separation reduced is $1$m. In time $t_0= \dfrac{84}{3x}$ A travels $(7*84)/3$m and the separation reduced is $84$m, that is both $A$ and $B$ coincide, so $(7*84)/3$m must be the winning post's distance.

My understanding is quite equivalent to unitary method but I am having difficulty in converting my method into unitary method.

Basically I want a proof/derivation of the fact that we can directly use unitary method there.

**Edit:** I realize that I need to understand unitary method, please give me some references for unitary method explanation.

Comment: Please attach proper tags with this and the [other](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1309218/103816) question; I don't know which tags are suitable.

Comment: Which text is this? I'd like to make sure not to use it, if it's saying things like "$7/4$ times *faster*" when it means "$7/4$ times *as fast*".

Comment: @CameronBuie It is 7/4 times _as fast_ I intentionally changed the text to make the title small but I think I changed the meaning -- I'm non-native English speaker.

Comment: I commend you on your excellent translation! That subtle point was the only confusing part of the post.